# Adding an unused instance fixes a type error

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass

Consider this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module Foo where

class Foo a

class SomeClass a
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (Foo a) => SomeClass a

bar :: (SomeClass a) => a -> Int
bar = const 0

foo :: (SomeClass a) => a -> Int
foo t = let x = bar t in x
```

Here, `foo` calls `bar`, and should be able to do so using the `SomeClass` constraint in its context. Instead, GHC assumes it must do so using the `Foo a => SomeClass a` instance:

```
Foo.hs:16:17:
    Could not deduce (Foo a) arising from a use of ‘bar’
    from the context (SomeClass a)
      bound by the type signature for foo :: SomeClass a => a -> Int
      at Foo.hs:15:8-32
    Possible fix:
      add (Foo a) to the context of
        the inferred type of x :: Int
        or the type signature for foo :: SomeClass a => a -> Int
    In the expression: bar t
    In an equation for ‘x’: x = bar t
    In the expression: let x = bar t in x
```

There are two ways to fix this:

1. In `foo`, changing `let x = bar t in x`  to `bar t`
2. Appending the line `instance SomeClass Int` to my program

What is going on here? Why is this problem occurring, and why do these fixes work?

---

This example is, of course, simplified by my actual problem. I encountered it during my work on the Cubix framework for multi-language transformation ( arxiv.org/pdf/1707.04600 ).

My actual problem involves a function with a constraint `InjF f IdentL FunctionExpL` ("f is a language where identifiers may be used to denote the function in a function call"). I have an (overlappable) instance `(FunctionIdent :<: f) => InjF f IdentL FunctionExpL`, which the typechecker seizes on, giving me a spurious `Could not deduce FunctionIdent :<: f` error.

This error persists even when there is an instance `InjF Foo IdentL FunctionExpL` in scope for a specific `Foo`, so leftaroundabout's answer, which predicts that that other instance should fix the problem, is not the full story.

Comment: The `{-# OVERLAPPABLE #-}` and `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` don't influence anything. Another way of getting compilation: add a `x :: Int` to the `let` binding.

Comment: Perhaps the silliest thing is that it also typechecks when there's _no instance at all_ in the module...

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is that the compiler tries to make `x` as general as possible: it wants it to be `(SomeClass a) => Int` (notice this would be an ambiguous type if you wrote it out yourself). One way to prevent this kind of weird local type is to enable `-XMonoLocalBinds`, but I wouldn't really recommend it.

Now, the compiler goes on to typechecking. At that point, there is exactly one `instance SomeClass` in scope, namely the catch-all `(Foo a) => SomeClass a`, so there's no ambiguity. (In principle, Haskell completely forbids ambiguity in instance resolution; `OVERLAPPABLE` subverts this but it only jumps into action when there's actually a need, like when you have an extra `instance SomeClass Int`.) Therefore, the compiler immediately commits to that instance and thus eliminates `(SomeClass a)` for the type-checking of `c`. That it does this is necessary for situations where you actually want a class constraint to be replaced by the constraint of an instance. This may seem useless in the given example, but it's actually crucial when you have instances of the form

```
instance Bar a => SomeClass (Maybe a)
```

...which is much more reasonable than your code because that *can't* be expressed as a superclass constraint, and is perfectly ok without any overlap. If the compiler didn't reduce the constraint resolving down to `Bar a` in those situations, it could never actually resolve down the `Maybe` type.

Conlusion: avoid overlapping instances; express class relations by superclass declarations if possible, else reify the constraints into a GADT (which is awkward but gives you exact control where which constraint is going to be used).

Comment: 1) What do you mean (Foo a => SomeClass a) is the only instance in scope? What about the (SomeClass a) constraint in the declaration?

Comment: 2) Why does it need to simplify the SomeClass (Maybe a) constraint immediately for it to simplify at all? Why can't it defer that resolution step till the end after it's already looked at the declaring context?

Comment: 3) This does help explain the simplified example I gave, but it falls short for the real example. I'll edit my post to also give the real example.

Comment: 4) So, can I summarize your answer as "the GHC typechecker has a bug in the presence of overlapping instances?" This very much does not sound like correct behavior; should it be reported?

Comment: I wish I could give you the karma of accepting this answer because, even though it doesn't entirely answer the question I asked, it did help me understand a different problem I've been facing the last 2 hours. My conclusion is that I should avoid let-statements in favor of case statements and where clauses. (Using where-clauses fixed a problem that simply annotating the LHS of a let-statement didn't, even though I thought they were equivalent.)